# I need to export a path which will available to all in windows command prompt

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, tensorflow, command-prompt

I need to export a path unix style so that i can use pip to download.

Unix command : export

```
TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.11.0rc2-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

What I need to do after it is exported on windows :

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

Comment: To make environmental variables available to all command sessions, you need to set them via Control Panel (search for *Environment*) or use `setx` (run `setx /?` from a command prompt).

Comment: Just copy the value of the variable below, it is not used after installation:
`pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.11.0rc2-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl`